# Automatically create symbolic links in Linux to files in one folder when a file in that folder is created and edited

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, symlink

I have 2 folders on my **Linux OS, Apache 2 Webserver**.
Call them **folderA and folderB** . They are have following paths

**site1/public/sites/all/folderA**

**site2/public/sites/all/folderB**

I would like that whenever a file is added/edited to folderA, a symlink is created/modified in folderB

Is there a way I can do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

folderB can be a symlink to folderA.

Comment: I had one query. If I make folderB symlink to folderA and later add files to folderA, will newly added files to folderA after the symlink has been created be accessible via folderB too?

Comment: I checked, they will be..thanks anyways for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) or [`inotifytools`](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/). They will watch for file creation or other activity and take an action that you designate.

Comment: Agreed. With `incron`, make a rule that will look like `site1/public/sites/all/folderA IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /path/to/your/script $@` where `$@` will contain the path to the created/modified file. Have a look at `man 5 incrontab` for more info.